# Return specific values in SQL for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to return only the values ​​that are in yellow in a SQL query for Access? I have not found a logic.

[image]

Comment: Can you not filter by that date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable1
WHERE DataFim = '08/10/2013'
```

Use the above if it is a string column.

If it is a datetime or date column you can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable1
WHERE DataFim =  CONVERT(DATETIME, '08/10/2013')
```

If you need to find all for the latest date that was entered as your comment implies, use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable1
WHERE DataFim IN (SELECT MAX(DataFim) FROM YourTable1)
```

Just for reference, if you didn't want to use `MAX()`, you could replace the last line with

```
WHERE DataFim IN (SELECT TOP 1 DataFim FROM YourTable1 ORDER BY DataFim DESC)
```

Which has the same effect but would also work on getting a string that is last when sorted alphabetically.

Comment: No no i need something similar to last or max.
Ex.: ... WHERE Last(DataFim)
... WHERE Max(DataFim)...

Answer (score 0):

Given your reply to Amber...

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE DataFim IN (SELECT MAX(DataFim) FROM TableName);
```