# Update specific values in SQL for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Continuing the topic [Return specific values in SQL for MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275667/return-specific-values-in-sql-for-ms-access) 
I have another situation:
How do I retrieve values ​​from the previous record set? Ie I want to retrieve the values ​​for the same corresponding previous gray turns yellow, where the values ​​are the red rectangle.

[image]

Comment: So you want to update IDFator 15-22 with the values from 7-14?

Comment: I can not be as specific to the IDFator, in continuation of the topic the link above, I needed to do this in a generic relative dates. Note that dates are 08/10/2013 to both, but there may be new records in the future.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the group on the left to the group on the right. Could you elaborate what you're updating?